# Unable to reload Visual Studio 2010 Project

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

By default Windows Form application in VS2010 is targeted to dot net Frame work 4.0 client profile for a windows form template ( i m not changing the original template but the newly created project).

but when I changed it to Dot net Frame work 4.0, the project is not loading into IDE.
It happens every time.

pleas help me.

Regards,
Akhil

Comment: What is the error message you get, what have you tried so far to resolve it and can you more precisely describe what you did to change the framework?

Comment: Try to delete the Project.suo file from the project's directory and try again.

Comment: @Justin:No Message is displayed, the project is in unloaded state (grayed).

Comment: @Sjoerd: what is the information stored in .suo file

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the same thing.  Try closing the solution and re-opening it.

Comment: It's not working, but when i create a blank solution and add that project in to the soln it's working.